# React: checker is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting this weird warning message in the console for my React app.

> Warning: Failed propType: checker is not a function Check the render method of `Chart`.

I do not have any checker method at all. If I remove my `propTypes`, the warning is gone. Any ideas?

My react component:

```js
var Chart = React.createClass({
  //...
  propTypes: {
    legend: React.PropTypes.bool,
    max: React.PropTypes.number,
    min: React.PropTypes.number,
    series: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
      React.PropTypes.shape({
        label: React.PropTypes.string,
        values: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
          React.PropTypes.arrayOf(
            React.PropTypes.oneOfType(
              React.PropTypes.number,
              React.PropTypes.object // Date
            )
          )
        ),
        colorIndex: React.PropTypes.string
      })
    ).isRequired,
    threshold: React.PropTypes.number,
    type: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['line', 'bar', 'area']),
    units: React.PropTypes.string,
    xAxis: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.string)
  },
  render: function() {
    return (<svg>...</svg>);
  }
  //...
});
```

The payload I send to the Chart component is this one:

```
var series = [
  {label: 'first', values: [[5,2], [4,3], [3,3], [2,2], [1,1]], colorIndex: "graph-1"},
  {label: 'second', values: [[5,3], [4,2], [3,0], [2,0], [1,0]], colorIndex: "graph-2"}
];
```

Comment: The impression I got from the error message is that somewhere inside the render method of your Chart component you are trying to call the "checker" method on something that does not have a "checker" method.

Comment: Sorry, but no. I've checked the Chart component and there is no call to checker. I checked React source code and they have some checker functions. But I have no idea how to fix that.

Comment: Copying and pasting your `propTypes` into a different project shows no errors, so I agree with @hugomg; this is probably an error down-stream from the `Chart` component (e.g. a bad propType in a child). If the bad prop type isn't easily identified, I would probably start deleting `propTypes` one by one to track it down.

Comment: The issue seems to be inside the series propTypes...I'm testing with REact 0.13.2. What about you guys?

Comment: v0.13.2 here as well... not sure why I'm not seeing the issue. Could it be that you didn't pass an array to `oneOfType`?

Comment: Good point, I've updated my question to include the payload. Seems right to me.

Comment: Can you provider your render function?

Comment: @AlanSouza I mean that `React.PropTypes.oneOfType(React.PropTypes.number, React.PropTypes.object)` should be `React.PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.number, React.PropTypes.object])`

Comment: Hey @BinaryMuse can you post this as an answer? That did the trick. I wish I could get a better log message. I will wait for you to post the answer so that I can accept that. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A pull request has been merged to the React repo that provides a better feedback for the developer whenever a mistake like this happens again.

Now, the validation message will look like the following:

> Invalid argument supplied to oneOf, expected an instance of array.

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3963

This should be part of React 0.14.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for submitting a PR to get this fixed

Comment: btw: This error message also appears when of the `PropType` in the array is invalid. I had `PropType.boolean` instead of `PropType.bool` and it wrote `Warning: Failed propType: checker is not a function Check the render method of` on react 0.14.3

Comment: interesting... maybe another Pull Request could be created!

Comment: In my case mistake was `PropTypes.function` rather than `PropTypes.func`

Comment: I've also seen this when you use nested objects in `PropTypes.shape` and forget to wrap the inner objects in `PropTypes.shape`.

Answer (score 126):

In my case I got this when I used the shape function with a complex object.
The solution was to go from:

```
outerObject: shape({
  firstInnerObject: {
    a: string,
    b: string,
  },
  secondInnerObject: {
    a: string,
    b: number,
  },
}),
```

To:

```
outerObject: shape({
  firstInnerObejct: shape({
    a: string,
    b: string,
  }),
  secondInnerObject: shape({
    a: string,
    b: number,
  }),
}),
```

Very trivial, I know, yet this might be the solution for someone equally inexperienced as I am. ;)

Comment: Holy heck 5 years later and I have to wonder how screwed I'd have been if you didn't solve this already.

Answer (score 13):

Change

```
React.PropTypes.oneOfType(React.PropTypes.number, React.PropTypes.object)
```

to

```
React.PropTypes.oneOfType([React.PropTypes.number, React.PropTypes.object])
```

(the argument should be an array)

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I was validating props wrong. I forgot to wrap the profile object into `PropTypes` shape method.

`Mistake`

```js
Component.propTypes = {
  viewProfile: PropTypes.shape({
    profile: {     // it is a normal object without a PropTypes shape method
      firstName: PropTypes.string,
      lastName: PropTypes.string,
      profileImage: PropTypes.string,
    },
  }).isRequired,
};
```

`Solution`

```js
Component.propTypes = {
  viewProfile: PropTypes.shape({
    profile: PropTypes.shape({
      firstName: PropTypes.string,
      lastName: PropTypes.string,
      profileImage: PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }).isRequired,
};
```

Answer (score 5):

FWIW, I was getting `Failed PropType: typeChecker is not a function`.  I noticed that in my `PropTypes.arrayOf()` properties, I was passing in an object of PropTypes e.g. `PropTypes.arrayOf({})`instead of passing in `PropTypes.shape()` e.g. `PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})`

Making this change eliminated the error message.

Answer (score 4):

My version of `Warning: Failed propType: checker is not a function` came from forgetting to use PropTypes.shape for an object.

Changing:

```
someProps: {
    prop: React.PropTypes.string,
    anotherProp: React.PropTypes.number,
}
```

to this fixed the problem:

```
someProps: React.PropTypes.shape({
    prop: React.PropTypes.string,
    anotherProp: React.PropTypes.number,
})
```

Answer (score 4):

The real explanation behind this issue is that react expects a PropType which is technically a function, aka **checker**. Examples for checker functions are:

```
PropTypes.array
PropTypes.shape({...})
PropTypes.bool
```

You got the idea... So what happens here is whenever you pass in something which isn't a checker, for example an `undefined`, react won't know what to do with this and so will complain:

> checker is not a function

In my case, the cause was misspelling of the checker functions:

```
PropTypes.shape({
    cats: PropTypes.Array // this is undefined
})
```

The correct version should be:

```
PropTypes.shape({
    cats: PropTypes.array // lowercase is correct!
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Reactv16

In my version of this ***error*** I had an array of objects:

```
data: PropTypes.shape([{
  id: PropTypes.number,
  ...
}])
```

The solution was to make an array of shapes like so:

```
data: PropTypes.arrayOf(
  PropTypes.shape({
    id: PropTypes.number,
    ...
  })
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I too got this error on putting proptypes in wrong format:

```
static propTypes = {
  workHard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  winBig: PropTypes.shape({
    prize: { // issue
      PENDING: PropTypes.bool,
    },
  }),
};
```

Turns out, prop types are expected to be either of type `PropTypes.shape` or `PropTypes.objectOf` when it comes to declaring `object` props

So, error was fixed upon changing code to this:

```
static propTypes = {
  workHard: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  winBig: PropTypes.shape({
    prize: PropTypes.shape({
      SUCCESS: PropTypes.bool,
    }),
  }),
};
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I'd simply accidentally removed a type:

```
grValue: PropTypes, // instead of PropTypes.string
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using `oneOfType` with array of strings as an argument when in fact I intended to use `oneOf`.

Something like that:

```
// Wrong!
PropTypes.oneOfType(['s', 'm'])

// Right!
PropTypes.oneOf(['s', 'm'])
```

Answer (score 0):

One more for the fun of it :)
In my case I extracted regularly used models into separate files and imported them. So the proptype definition looked something like this:

```
 static propTypes = {
        ...
        selectedAction: shape(ACTION),
        ...
};
```

My error was that I wrote an additional curly in the shape:

```
static propTypes = {
        ...
        selectedAction: shape({ACTION}),
        ...
};
```