# React Warning: "Failed prop type: checker is not a function"

Tags: reactjs

I'm getting this warning (`Failed prop type: checker is not a function`) when I add this to my `PropTypes`:

```
errorMessage: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
  React.PropTypes.string,
  React.PropTypes.boolean,
]),
```

I've checked this question: [React: checker is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29995444/react-checker-is-not-a-function) but all the answers there suggest to use `React.PropTypes.oneOfType([...])` instead of `React.PropTypes.oneOfType(...)`.

I am already using an array inside the `.oneOfType` so I am lost here. I've checked my prop `errorMessage` and it is fine, it starts as `false` a then when an error appears it is converted to a `string`. It doesn't get any other type.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try change from: `React.PropTypes.boolean` to `React.PropTypes.bool`

Comment: That solved it. Thanks!

I wonder why they chose to use `bool` instead of `boolean` and why the error message is so unrelated.

Comment: For others seeing this: Try changing every proptype you have like `objectOf` or `arrayOf` to `object` and `array`. I guess they deprecated these types in favor of the more simpler ones.